# Como llamar un string de valores multiples desde un ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin

estoy tratando de llamar un string que acepta dos valores desde un viewmodel

```
<string name="send_message">Se envió %1$s a %2$s</string>
```

con la siguiente función

```
private fun getString(textId: Int,args: ArrayList<Any>) =
            getApplication<Application>().applicationContext?.getString(textId, args) ?: ""

val message = getString(R.string.mystring, arrayListOf(amount,name))
```

Pero me marca el siguiente error

> ```
> java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%2$s'
> ```

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal? se los agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0):

Como segundo parametro de getString() no debes usar el ArrayList directamente, debes obtener los elementos dentro del ArrayList.

```
private fun getStringMessage(textId: Int, args: ArrayList<String>) : String =
        applicationContext?.getString(textId, args[0], args[1]) ?: ""
```

y llamas de esta forma la función:

```
    val message = getStringMessage(R.string.send_message, arrayListOf(amount,name))
```

Comment: lo que pasa que también uso el método para cuando solo es un string y puede que sean igual hasta 5 o 4 strings aveces